# Naming a chat group with The Lee or Lee's

Tags: grammaticality

I want to start a WhatsApp group and I don't know which of the following names is grammatically correct:

Lee Family 

The Lee Family

Lee's Family

The Lee's Family.

Comment: Assuming this family is headed up by, for example, Mr and Mrs Lee, the standard format would be *The Lee Family*. But if we're talking about the family of, say, Lee Smith, it would be *Lee's Family*. The first version (without *"the"*) is credible, but unlikely. The last version simply isn't credible in any context I can think of.

Comment: _The Lees_ is also fine (apart from possible associations).

Comment: The Simpsons; The Simpson family; Homer Simpson's family. The Lees; The Lee family; John Lee's family.

Comment: I though this question would be voted for closing by the EL&U experts, **after seeing http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2259/65072**

Comment: Naming is off-topic here, although asking what to call a family like this is probably fine. I wouldn't be surprised if it's a duplicate though.

Comment: @user1661558 which of the suggested names are or are not grammatically correct is on-topic (whether it's also a GR or not, or also a duplicate or not, is another matter).

Comment: @JonHanna thanks for the clarification :) Personally I wouldn't dare ask this kind of question here. I would rather use YA! for simple questions/suggestions.

Comment: @user1661558 I'm not sure I'd use YA! for anything, but certainly not for anything with the phrase "is grammatically correct" as part of the question.

Comment: @JonHanna I've used YA! for quite a long time and it really has got many experts. The advantage of asking/answering a question in YA! is that no one down-votes (except flagging). So, after posting something, I don't have to be worried. However, I agree that EL&U is much useful(and **stricter**) than any other QA site

Comment: @user1661558, I know I can depend on EVERYONE being kept honest on this site! lol!

Comment: @user1661558 it's true that with the YA format, you don't have to worry that your answer might be completely useless or hopelessly wrong, but that isn't a completely good thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Lee Family

Perfectly normal, plain English.

> Lee Family

The above, in headline style (hence leaving out the *the* that one would normally leave in).

> ?Lee's Family

Suggests the family of a single individual called Lee. Presumably, not what you mean.

> *The Lee's Family

Suggests the above and then puts an article where it doesn't belong.

> The Lees

Just pluralises *Lee*. Fine.

> ?The Lee's

Pluralises *Lee* using a style for pluralising surnames that used to once be used, but is now so old-fashioned as to be practically obsolete. Avoid.

> ?The Lees' Family

The family of all the Lees. But then, the Lees' family **is** the Lees. Arguably valid, but pretty strange.

Comment: Excellent explanation of the major options and mistakes. Thanks!